# Ajax ModalPopupExtender with DataGrid bound Hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I am currently developing an ASP.net c# application. I have an Ajax Modal Popup Extender which I currently have working with an asp:button for testing purposes which I have got working fine.

However, what I need to be able to do is I have a hyperlink bound to a dataset being populated from a MySQL Database. The hyperlink passes parameters based on database columns. What I need to be able to do is to open the modal popup extender and display dynamic data based on the paramaters from the hyperlink url.

Hope this makes sense, thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a LinkButton, open the ModalPopup in the click event of the LinkButton by calling the `Show` method. Process any data that you want to display in the panel before you display it.

Comment: thanks for the help. Its not a linkbutton its just a hyperlink column template inside the datagrid unless that's the same thing.